# WCF transaction over multiple services

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, transactionscope

A client application is calling 2 different WCF services in one TransactionScope, in the hopes of rolling back the entire transaction if one of the calls fails like this:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{

     proxy1.UpdateThing(data);
     proxy2.UpdateSomeOtherThing(data);

     transaction.Complete();
}
```

Now, the call to proxy1 is fine, but the call to proxy2 throws an exception.
Still the call to proxy1 has succeeded when I check the database.

How should I go to work in this scenario? Are DependentTransactions the way to go here?

Both services are hosted on the same machine, both have a wsHttpBinding with TransactionFlow = true. The transaction works for each service in isolation, it's when a call used both services, like in the example, that doesn't work.
Both services are decorated with the correct annotations.

The exception is just a hard throw in one of the services, for testing this.

It's worth noting that both services use EF to process their data to the database.

Comment: Is the proxy1 endpoint and/or operation able to handle transactions?
If the services for proxy1 and proxy2 are under your control, maybe check this article to enable distributed transactions: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/81a718/simple-steps-to-enable-transactions-in-wcf/

Comment: Yep, both have TransactionFlow on the interface and TransactionScopeRequired set on the relevant methods.

Comment: What bindings are you using? Some bindings don't support transactions.

Comment: wsHttpBinding. In isolation the transactional behavior works for both services. It's just when I start crossing services boundaries it doesn;t hold up.

Comment: It's just a hard throw in the code to test this.

Answer (score 2):

To enable transactions in WCF you need a lot more as a transaction scope in you consumer.

To add transaction support to a WCF service, you will take the following actions:

- Add transaction support to the service contract. This is required.
- Add transaction support to the code that implements the service
  contract. This is required.
- Configure transactions in the
  implementation code. This is optional.
- Enable transactions on the
  binding. This is required.

To start a transaction in the client application, you must take the following actions:

- Add transaction support to the proxy class.
- Enable transactions on the binding.
- Use the TransactionScope class to start a transaction.

To read how to implement this you can read (source): [Transactions in WCF Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384250.aspx)

Comment: Yes, like stated in the OP, the transactional behavior works for either service in isolation. Just when we cross services boundaries it starts falling apart.

Comment: @Apeiron did this apprach solve the problem, what approach did you finally take?